# How do I handle errors from libc functions in an idiomatic Rust manner?

Tags: error-handling, rust, libc

libc's error handling is usually to return something `< 0` in case of an error. I find myself doing this over and over:

```
let pid = fork()
if pid < 0 {
    // Please disregard the fact that `Err(pid)`
    // should be a `&str` or an enum
    return Err(pid);
}
```

I find it ugly that this needs 3 lines of error handling, especially considering that these tests are quite frequent in this kind of code.

Is there a way to return an `Err` in case `fork()` returns `< 0`?

I found two things which are close:

1. `assert_eq!`. This needs another line and it `panic`s so the caller cannot handle the error.
2. Using traits like these:

   ```
   pub trait LibcResult<T> {
       fn to_option(&self) -> Option<T>;
   }

   impl LibcResult<i64> for i32 {
       fn to_option(&self) -> Option<i64> {
           if *self < 0 { None } else { Some(*self) }
       }
   }
   ```

I could write `fork().to_option().expect("could not fork")`. This is now only one line, but it `panic`s instead of returning an `Err`. I guess this could be solved using `ok_or`.

Some functions of libc have `< 0` as sentinel (e.g. [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html#RETURN_VALUE)), while others use `> 0` (e.g. [`pthread_attr_init`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_init.3.html#RETURN_VALUE)), so this would need another argument.

Is there something out there which solves this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As indicated in the other answer, use pre-made wrappers whenever possible. Where such wrappers do not exist, the following guidelines might help.

#### Return `Result` to indicate errors

The idiomatic Rust return type that includes error information is `Result` ([`std::result::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html)). For most functions from POSIX libc, the specialized type [`std::io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html) is a perfect fit because it uses [`std::io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html) to encode errors, and it includes all standard system errors represented by `errno` values. A good way to avoid repetition is using a utility function such as:

```
use std::io::{Result, Error};

fn check_err<T: Ord + Default>(num: T) -> Result<T> {
    if num < T::default() {
        return Err(Error::last_os_error());
    }
    Ok(num)
}
```

Wrapping `fork()` would look like this:

```
pub fn fork() -> Result<u32> {
    check_err(unsafe { libc::fork() }).map(|pid| pid as u32)
}
```

The use of `Result` allows idiomatic usage such as:

```
let pid = fork()?;  // ? means return if Err, unwrap if Ok
if pid == 0 {
    // child
    ...
}
```

#### Restrict the return type

The function will be easier to use if the return type is modified so that only "possible" values are included. For example, if a function logically has no return value, but returns an `int` only to communicate the presence of error, the Rust wrapper should return nothing:

```
pub fn dup2(oldfd: i32, newfd: i32) -> Result<()> {
    check_err(unsafe { libc::dup2(oldfd, newfd) })?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Another example are functions that logically return an unsigned integer, such as a PID or a file descriptor, but still declare their result as signed to include the -1 error return value. In that case, consider returning an unsigned value in Rust, as in the `fork()` example above. `nix` takes this one step further by having `fork()` return `Result<ForkResult>`, where `ForkResult` is a real enum with methods such as `is_child()`, and from which the PID is extracted using pattern matching.

#### Use options and other enums

Rust has a rich type system that allows expressing things that have to be encoded as magic values in C. To return to the `fork()` example, that function returns 0 to indicate the child return. This would be naturally expressed with an `Option` and can be combined with the `Result` shown above:

```
pub fn fork() -> Result<Option<u32>> {
    let pid = check_err(unsafe { libc::fork() })? as u32;
    if pid != 0 {
        Some(pid)
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

The user of this API would no longer need to compare with the magic value, but would use pattern matching, for example:

```
if let Some(child_pid) = fork()? {
    // execute parent code
} else {
    // execute child code
}
```

#### Return values instead of using output parameters

C often returns values using *output parameters*, pointer parameters into which the results are stored. This is either because the actual return value is reserved for the error indicator, or because more than one value needs to be returned, and returning structs was badly supported by historical C compilers.

In contrast, Rust's `Result` supports return value independent of error information, and has no problem whatsoever with returning multiple values. Multiple values returned as a tuple are much more ergonomic than output parameters because they can be used in expressions or captured using pattern matching.

#### Wrap system resources in owned objects

When returning handles to system resources, such as file descriptors or Windows handles, it good practice to return them wrapped in an object that implements `Drop` to release them. This will make it less likely that a user of the wrapper will make a mistake, and it makes the use of return values more idiomatic, removing the need for awkward invocations of `close()` and resource leaks coming from failing to do so.

Taking `pipe()` as an example:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd;

pub fn pipe() -> Result<(File, File)> {
    let mut fds = [0 as libc::c_int; 2];
    check_err(unsafe { libc::pipe(fds.as_mut_ptr()) })?;
    Ok(unsafe { (File::from_raw_fd(fds[0]), File::from_raw_fd(fds[1])) })
}

// Usage:
// let (r, w) = pipe()?;
// ... use R and W as normal File object
```

This `pipe()` wrapper returns multiple values and uses a wrapper object to refer to a system resource. Also, it returns the `File` objects defined in the Rust standard library and accepted by Rust's IO layer.

Comment: great roundup about handling libc's return types in general! This would be nice as a documentation post

Answer (score 5):

The *best* option is to not reimplement the universe. Instead, use [nix](https://crates.io/crates/nix), which wraps everything for you and has done the hard work of converting all the error types and handling the sentinel values:

```
pub fn fork() -> Result<ForkResult>
```

Then just [use normal error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html) like `try!` or `?`.

---

Of course, you could rewrite all of nix by converting your trait to returning `Result`s and including the specific error codes and then use `try!` or `?`, but why would you?

There's nothing magical in Rust that converts negative or positive numbers into a domain specific error type for you. The code you already have is the correct approach, once you've enhanced it to use a `Result` either by creating it directly or via something like `ok_or`.

An intermediate solution would be to reuse nix's `Errno` struct, perhaps with your own trait sugar on top.

> so this would need another argument

I'd say it would be better to have different methods: one for negative sentinel values and one for positive sentinel values.

Comment: sure, `fork` was just a dummy example. Where I'm currently stuck is `pthread_attr_init` which currently seems not supported by `nix` yet

Comment: @hansaplast then it seems like the correct solution is to submit a PR to nix adding that. Then you would just use whatever mechanism they have already established for converting error codes to elegant types.

Comment: @hansaplast remember you can also temporarily fork nix to use your local changes while the PR is being reviewed. That way you aren't stuck waiting.

Comment: thanks, I have a bit a special case where I am porting C code of a book to Rust and want to stay as close to syscalls as possible for educational purposes, so I guess I'll go the way where I'll write a trait with a method per sentinel